# Is there any wysiwyg app which I can use to make the frontend pages of a sinmple django webapp?

Tags: python, django

I've never done any web development before. I'm using django because I'm OK at python. I just want to make a small webapp which does a small task fast...

Answer (score 1):

I found all wysiwyg editors I've used are much more confusing to use than just some plain old html. It is super easy to get started. Do it in plain html.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/ for example. It is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this http://developers.whatwg.org/introduction.html#introduction will be perfect start up point for creating frontend pages. Forget about wysiwyg - it is suitable only for simple content modifications.